# How to Aggregate Data from a Subquery that Requires a Filter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Sorry if the title is confusing, I'll try to explain. I have a query that needs to have a couple of aggregate fields, but I don't know how to write one of them. Here's the current script:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
DECLARE @FromDate VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @ToDate VARCHAR(25);

SET     @Date = GETDATE();
SET     @FromDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(@Date) - 1), @Date),101);
SET     @ToDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @Date))), DATEADD(mm,1,@Date)), 101);

SELECT  DISTINCT    [A].[Name],
                    COUNT([O].[Id]) AS [OpportunityCount],
                    (CASE WHEN (SUM([O].[Amount]) IS NULL) THEN 0.00 ELSE SUM([O].[Amount]) END) AS [OpportunityTotalAmounts]
                    --(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Opportunity] AS [O1] WHERE ([O1].[Id] = [O].[Id]) AND ([O1].[StageName] != 'Not Sold'))
FROM                [Account] AS [A]
                    JOIN [RecordType] AS [RT] ON ([A].[RecordTypeId] = [RT].[Id])
                    JOIN [Contact] AS [C] ON ([A].[Id] = [C].[AccountId])
                    JOIN [OpportunityContactRole] AS [OCR] ON ([C].[Id] = [OCR].[ContactId])
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Opportunity] AS [O] ON ([OCR].[OpportunityId] = [O].[Id])
WHERE               ([RT].[Name] = 'PHX')
                    AND ([A].[TypeMS__c] != 'Customer')
                    AND ([O].[CreatedDate] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
GROUP BY            [A].[Name];
```

You'll notice a commented out line. On that line I want to get a count of all `Opportunities` that are not marked as `'Not Sold'`. It works if I add `[O].[Id]` to the `GROUP BY`, but then the result set expands because the grouping gets messed up.

How can I get the count I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you know about the ISNULL function, but the CASE you have in here checking for it can be written ISNULL(SUM([O].[Amount]), 0.00).

Comment: I did not, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
DECLARE @FromDate VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @ToDate VARCHAR(25);

SET     @Date = GETDATE();
SET     @FromDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(@Date) - 1), @Date),101);
SET     @ToDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @Date))), DATEADD(mm,1,@Date)), 101);

SELECT  DISTINCT    [A].[Name],
                    COUNT([O].[Id]) AS [OpportunityCount],
                    (CASE WHEN (SUM([O].[Amount]) IS NULL) THEN 0.00 ELSE SUM([O].[Amount]) END) AS [OpportunityTotalAmounts],
                    SUM(CASE WHEN [O].[StageName] != 'Not Sold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM                [Account] AS [A]
                    JOIN [RecordType] AS [RT] ON ([A].[RecordTypeId] = [RT].[Id])
                    JOIN [Contact] AS [C] ON ([A].[Id] = [C].[AccountId])
                    JOIN [OpportunityContactRole] AS [OCR] ON ([C].[Id] = [OCR].[ContactId])
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Opportunity] AS [O] ON ([OCR].[OpportunityId] = [O].[Id])
WHERE               ([RT].[Name] = 'PHX')
                    AND ([A].[TypeMS__c] != 'Customer')
                    AND ([O].[CreatedDate] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
GROUP BY            [A].[Name];
```

This is the trick, you already defined a join so you just need to Sum the StageName  differents from Not Sold using a `CASE` statement

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN [O].[StageName] != 'Not Sold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Well, this was much simpler than I imagined it would be... Thanks!